# How to draw HTML class cards

Tags: html, jquery, css, sql, ajax

I need to use HTML class cards to show certain data on my page.

This is the style that I'm using.

```
<style>
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.row {margin: 0 -5px;}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
```

This is the HTML code that I'm using to draw the card.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <div id="roomList" class="card">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm using ajax to load the data from SQL. After the data is loaded to ajax the data is appended to the roomList in order to create the card.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/HouseKeeping/OutOfOrderTXN/RoomList',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            $.each(data, function (index, eachRoomList) {
                $('#roomList').append( 
                    '<div class="row"><div class="column"><div class="card"> data-room-id="' + eachRoomList.Id + '" data-room-name="' + eachRoomList.RoomName + '"</div></div></div>>');
            })
        },
        error: function (error) {

        }
    });
```

`+ eachRoomList.RoomName +` The data which is loaded to this are eg=100,101,102

But it doesn't work. Below is a picture of how my class card is drawn.

The data is not shown inside the class 'card' for eg-100 should be shown inside the class 'card'
whats wrong with my code.I'm a beginner so help me pls

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7NKa.jpg)

Comment: can you please provide us with the sample data of your response? 100,101,102 are in what form? array, object?

Comment: @kokila it comes as a json but I have taken only the  important things i mean the data which i should show in the class=card

Comment: Is your ajax request successful? Are you getting the data from backend and just having problem displaying it?

Comment: @kokila yes it's successful. The data is also retrieved by ajax from SQL. In my question in ajax code, (+ eachRoomList.RoomName +) part gets a value for eg 100 from SQL..that value should be  show  in my class =card.The error is in displaying the value 100

Comment: what does `data` has in it ? can you add that as well in your question?

Comment: @Swati it contains the data of the json that i receive from SQL

Comment: can you do `alert(data)` inside your ajax success and show it ? maybe data is null

Comment: @Swati the values inside data (1: {Id: 3, RoomId: 0, FromDate: "/Date(-62135596800000)/", ToDate: "/Date(-62135596800000)/", OutOfOrderReasonId: 0, …})

Answer (score 0):

[image: image of my html]
If your ajax request is successful,there is a problem in appending the child.
Your class="card" div is not closed.
Can you try

```
$('#roomList').append(`<div class="row"><div class="column">   <div class="card" data-room-id="${eachRoomList.Id}" data-room-name="${eachRoomLi[![enter image description here][1]][1]st.RoomName}">${eachRoomList.RoomName}</div></div></div>`);
```

Comment: Like my code everything works even in your code the only thing is [ RoomName] value is not shown on the class=card even I have appended it. So for example if RoomName contains 100 it is not shown on the appended class as 100.It shows like above picture in my question

Comment: I am using this sample data and it works just fine 

 let s = [{ Id: "1", RoomName: "100" }, { Id: "2", RoomName: "101" }];

Comment: Is the card also being shown with the value?,In my case, there's only a small box without any value in it (like in my question -Image).I think the error is in my style or in my append .

Comment: Did you check the image i attached in my question /

Comment: I have seen the image you have attached. I am getting the card as well as the value

Comment: I'm using two tabs. First, one is used to show a gird, Second one is the one I'm using to show the cards. Can this happen because of this problem?

Comment: Might be. I will need to see the code to understand it. Check the image attached.